# Should repeated integers be converted into factors before applying regression technique

Tags: r, regression

I am new to data science, so sorry in advance if this question seems stupid.

I have a data set which has 1463 observation and two of the variables are like .

```
OverallCond: Rates the overall condition of the house

   10   Very Excellent
   9    Excellent
   8    Very Good
   7    Good
   6    Above Average   
   5    Average
   4    Below Average   
   3    Fair
   2    Poor
   1    Very Poor

MSSubClass: Identifies the type of dwelling involved in the sale.   

    20  1-STORY 1946 & NEWER ALL STYLES
    30  1-STORY 1945 & OLDER
    40  1-STORY W/FINISHED ATTIC ALL AGES
    45  1-1/2 STORY - UNFINISHED ALL AGES
    50  1-1/2 STORY FINISHED ALL AGES
    60  2-STORY 1946 & NEWER
    70  2-STORY 1945 & OLDER
    75  2-1/2 STORY ALL AGES
    80  SPLIT OR MULTI-LEVEL
    85  SPLIT FOYER
    90  DUPLEX - ALL STYLES AND AGES
   120  1-STORY PUD (Planned Unit Development) - 1946 & NEWER
   150  1-1/2 STORY PUD - ALL AGES
   160  2-STORY PUD - 1946 & NEWER
   180  PUD - MULTILEVEL - INCL SPLIT LEV/FOYER
   190  2 FAMILY CONVERSION - ALL STYLES AND AGES
```

Should I convert these variables into factors before applying regression as they are repeated  or should I treat them as integers only?

Comment: `OverallCond` is a. ordered variable so I'd keep it as an integer. `MSSubClass` is difficult because there seem to be so many levels (i.e. different values) as a factor variable. In order to know the number of unique values in the variable, you can run `length(unique(MSSubClass))`. If the number is large, I'd think to convert them to several variables by extracting information (e.g. the number of stories, a binary variable for a foyer or not etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MysticRenge wrote - YES.

But it is important you understand the *why* behind it:
Any regression models have a certain way of calculating the coefficients, and broadly speaking in OLS regression, its checking the mean value of the dependent variable (Y) for each value of the independent variable (controlling for other independent ones) and doing a weighted arithmetic mean of those. So a coefficient is the average linear increase (or decrease) in Y, for every addition of one unit of X.

If you leave the coding of categorical variables as an integer, the model will handle them like continuous quantitative variables, and the *meaning* of the coefficient will be by how much Y increases for every single-unit increase in X. Since the categorical have no uniform interval (or order in the case of the second variable), this will be meaningless.

Transforming them to dummy variables (via `as.factor()`) will coerce the categories into pairs, leaving out one category. The new meaning of each coefficient now will be the average difference in Y between category i of X, and the category left out. If you want to change this comparison category, use the `relevel()` function.

Answer (score 0):

These variables should be converted to factor variables. Also, the variable MSSubClass looks like it will have too many levels so you may need to manage that as well. For example you could combine levels together to make one level!

Comment: For example: 2-STORY 1946 & NEWER & 2-STORY 1945 & OLDER could be combined to make one level for example (after converting the column into categorical)